# What is the complexity of this pseudo-code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, pseudocode

I found this excersise in the exam and I ecountered difficulty to solve the problem.

I can suppuse for sure the algorithm will take at least O(n) due the for, but I don't know how to approach the while. I know that in this case i have to evaluate the worst if-else branch and for sure it is the second one.

```
for i=1...n do
    j=n
    while i<j do
        if j mod 2 = 0 then j=j-1
        else j=i
```

intuitively i think the total cost is: O(nlogn)=O(n)*O(logn)

Comment: Your inner loop has (pretty much) constant time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In short**: the `while` loop will *each* time run at most two iterations. This makes the algorithm *O(n)*.

The `while` loop will iterate at most two times. Indeed let us take a look at the while loop:

```
while i < j do
    if j mod 2 = 0 then
        j=j-1
    else
        j=i
```

It is clear that we will only execute the `while` loop if `i < j`. Furthermore if `j mod 2 == 1` (so `j` is *odd*), then it will set `j = i`, and thus the while loop will no longer run.

If on the other hand `j mod 2 == 0` (so `j` is *even*), then we decrement `j`. There are now two things that could happen, either `i == j`, in which case we do not perform an extra iteration. If we however perform an extra iteration, the `if` condition will fail, since decrementing an *even* number results in an *odd* number. Since we each time set `j = n`, it also means that the number of steps that the while loop performs is determined by `n` itself.

This thus means that regardless what the values for `i` and `j` are, the body of the `while` loop will be performed at most two times.

Since we perform the `while` loop extactly `n` times, it thus means that the algorithm is still ***O(n)***. We here make the assumption that we can check the parity of a number and decrement a number in constant time.

Comment: Thank you very much Willem, I was too focused on the nested loop thinking that i have to iterate more or less n time per n value! You have been super clear :)

Answer (score 3):

Does `mod` refer to Modulo? In that case, the while loop will evaluate at most twice; once to decrement `j`, but then `j mod 2` will be `1`, and after setting `j=i` your `i<j` will be false. The complexity difference here oscillates rather than increases with input, and is thus O(1) for this branch.